# Scraping Json table too pandas with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get data from this website? It seems a json structure. It possible get it with BeautifulSoup?

url: https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/statsLeadersTable?current=1&rowCount=-1&sort%5Bvalue%5D=desc&searchPhrase=&category=aces&season=&fromDate=&toDate=&level=&bestOf=&surface=&indoor=&speed=&round=&result=&tournamentId=&opponent=&countryId=&minEntries=&active=true&_=1622884929848

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: You don't need BeautifulSoup. It is indeed JSON. you can use `r.json()` and get data into dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct pandas dataframe from the data directly. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/statsLeadersTable?current=1&rowCount=-1&sort%5Bvalue%5D=desc&searchPhrase=&category=aces&season=&fromDate=&toDate=&level=&bestOf=&surface=&indoor=&speed=&round=&result=&tournamentId=&opponent=&countryId=&minEntries=&active=true&_=1622884929848"
data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data["rows"])
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
     rank  playerId                          name  value               country.name country.id country.code
0       1      3333                  Ivo Karlovic  13687                    Croatia        CRO           hr
1       2      4544                    John Isner  12806              United States        USA           us
2       3      3819                 Roger Federer  11371                Switzerland        SUI           ch
3       5      3852               Feliciano Lopez   9920                      Spain        ESP           es
4       8      5016                   Sam Querrey   8466              United States        USA           us
5       9      5670                  Milos Raonic   8130                     Canada        CAN           ca
6      13      4728                Kevin Anderson   7262               South Africa        RSA           za
7      14      5220                   Marin Cilic   7246                    Croatia        CRO           hr
8      17      4541            Jo Wilfried Tsonga   6634                     France        FRA           fr
9      18      4789                  Gael Monfils   6245                     France        FRA           fr
10     20      4920                Novak Djokovic   6069                     Serbia        SRB           rs
11     21      4526                 Stan Wawrinka   5900                Switzerland        SUI           ch

...
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]